# What preposition does "rate ... criteria" take?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm writing up specs for a website with learning materials for our alpha testers to comment on. Among others, I'm describing the rating system: the materials can be rated (...) several criteria (such as usefulness, quality), e.g. by giving 3 stars for usefulness and 5 for quality.

Is "according to" the only proper way to link "rate" and "criteria" in this case? Can we *rate **by** quality*? *rate **on** quality*? *'rate **in** quality'*?

I would usually just say *'rate **the** quality'*, without a preposition or anything, but I can't really use that in a passive sentence about the materials, and I know that even if I change this specific sentence into an active one, I'll need the passive at some point as well...

(please note that I mean the act of rating (ie. giving stars or votes or whatever), not the act of sorting things by their ratings - which is I suspect why the ***'by'*** and ***'according to'*** options don't sound right to me)

Comment: I don't think any of those prepositions are right. *Rate the quality* conveys exactly what you want. And I don't see the problem with the passive:"The quality can be rated". You could also say "rate in terms of quality".

Comment: What I meant by the passive was using "material" as the object: "The material can be rated ... quality". "in terms of" sounds like it might work...

Comment: Oh,I see. Well, "for quality" would work too.

Comment: I think in your context you are using criteria to rate, so I would use "using" to join the words; rating using the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious rewording that fixes this issue is:

> The material's quality can be rated.

But if you want to keep your original form, the best preposition would be:

> The material can be rated for quality.

Relevant NGram data for ["rated * quality"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rated+%2a+quality&year_start=1900) show that "for" beats out "on" and "by" by significant margins.

Comment: Thanks - didn't think of "for", it does seem to fit my needs the best.